# How to copy both - HTML and text to the clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, clipboard

I'm trying to put in the clipboard piece of HTML and plain text at the same time, so that HTML-capable editors could paste HTML, and other editors could use plain text.

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, htmlWithHeader);
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, plainText);
```

But only the last format is actually put to the clipboard. In the sample above, clipboard would contain only plaintext (as shown by  `Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()`). And if I swap the lines, the clipboard would have only the HTML format.

How can I put both formats into the clipboard at the same time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can NOT use `Clipboard.SetData` for setting both HTML and plain text. The second call of SetData will clear the content of clipboard that has been set by first call and store the new data.

You should use [DataObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataobject.aspx) and [Clipboard.SetDataObject()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5b8kt5z4.aspx).

Example:

```
DataObject dataObj = new DataObject();
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Html, htmlWithHeader);
dataObj.SetData(DataFormats.Text, plainText);

Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
```

Comment: Would it not be better to retrieve what was in `Clipboard` then create your `DataObject` off of that then add your who items? That way you don't remove the existing `Clipboard` date?

Comment: @Bob, NO!  That would create a hybrid franken-clip, which could have data from different apps.  Suppose you have RTF on the clipboard, then you add plaintext from one app, html from another app, and then bitmap from yet another app.  When you paste into Notepad, you'd get the plaintext. When you paste into MS Paint, you'd get the bitmap. When you paste into WinWord, who knows?  This is not the way the clipboard is supposed to work.