# Copy as html to clipboard programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, clipboard

My problem is that user could get html copied to his clipboard without selecting it manually and **Ctrl** + **C**.
The problem is that all plugins i tried (zClip, ZeroClipboard) copy just plain text. And then if i paste it into the Microsoft Word for example just text is pasted but not html which it represents.
Is there any way to do that?
I tried to find solution for my problem here and on the rest of the web but i couldnt.

```
window.zclip_copyTaskReference = function (event) {
    debugger;
    try {
        var self = $(event.target);
        var taskId = self.attr('data-task-id');
        var taskName = self.attr('data-task-name');
        var href = location.href.replace(/[#]$/, '');
        var link = $('<a></a>');
        link.attr('href', href);
        link.text(taskName);
        var html = link.wrap($('<div/>')).parent().html();
        successMessage('Link copied to clipboard');
        //return link[0];
        return html.trim();
        //return (html);
    } catch (e) {
        errorMessage('Failed to copy link');
        return '';
    }
};
```

init:

```
    $('.copy-link').zclip({
        path: '/Scripts/jquery/zclip/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: window.zclip_copyTaskReference,
        afterCopy: $.noop()
    });
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286957/how-to-copy-both-html-and-text-to-the-clipboard) question on StackOverflow. It tells a clear solution! :)

Comment: Sorry, i forgot about that it must be Web solution Javascript/Flash

Comment: anything you have tried yet? please post the code. let me figure out the error

Comment: well, wherever I search I get a ZeroClipboard solution.. I think that you have done something wrong in your code... please post it!

Comment: added the code sample i am using

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping that code within either `<pre>` tags or `<code>` tags.  If that doesn't work, you should be able to grab the content with jQuery's [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, serialize that into a string, and copy it to the clipboard.