# How to set clipboard's plain text and html part at the same time in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When I copy some rich text from browser, the plain text part and html part of clipboard is existing at the same time.

But when I try to set clipboard in Powershell, they could not be set at the same time.

For example, `Set-Clipboard -Value "abc"` will set the plain text part of clipboard (and flush the html part) so that using `Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType html` will get blank.  While `Get-Content "a.html" | Set-Clipboard -AsHtml` will set the html part and flush the plain text part of clipboard, so that using `Get-Clipboard` will get nothing.

How could I set clipboard's plain text and html part at the same time in Powershell?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can set the clipboard twice. How ever for me works the follwoing: `Get-Clipboard -TextFormatType Html`

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [How to copy both - HTML and text to the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286957/how-to-copy-both-html-and-text-to-the-clipboard)

The following powershell script works.

```
$data = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataObject
$data.SetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Html, $text)
$data.SetData([System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::Text, $html)
[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::SetDataObject($data)
```